# contextual binding in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Normally i do like this

1. for `loops`

   ```
   # app/view/products/index.html.haml
   - @products.each do |product|
      = product.name
      = product.foo
      = product.bar
   ```
2. normal `scoping`

   ```
   # app/view/products/show.html.haml 
     = @product.name
     = @product.price
     = @product.xyz
   ```

See in above situation, i am repeating myself. I am using same `product` word every time. I want it something like which could attach/bind the `method` as per my context.

I rather prefer to do something like this

1. For `loops` i like do something like

   ```
    - @products.each(context_binding: true) do 
      = name
      = foo
      = bar
   ```
2. for `scoping`

   ```
    - context_binding @product do 
      = name
      = price
      = xyz
   ```

I guess that is possible and can be done with `method missing` i dont know how to do it. Can you give some hints so i can archive such type of things.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea:

```
class With
  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj
    @str = ''
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    @str += @obj.send(name, *args, &block).to_s
  end
end

def with(obj, &block)
  With.new(obj).instance_eval(&block).to_s
end

Product = Struct.new(:name, :price)
product = Product.new('apple', '2')

output = with(product) do
  name
  price
end

puts output
```

Comment: Yep, but where would you put the file? In `lib`?